# I'm facing an error when I use tkinter canvas. It is not able to find the image. How to fix it?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
entry0_img = PhotoImage(file=f"img_textBox0.png")
print('1')
# ... (the rest of your Tkinter code)
entry0_bg = canvas.create_image(
    737.0, 234.0,
    image = entry0_img)
```

It loads the image, and print '1' . Then there comes a error in canvas.create_image().

im attaching the error below:

```
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Code\gra-eng\Fre-eng.ipynb Cell 40 line 1
     98 print('1')
     99 # ... (the rest of your Tkinter code)
--> 100 entry0_bg = canvas.create_image(
    101     737.0, 234.0,
    102     image = entry0_img)
    103 result_label = Label(
    104     text="Predicted Translation:",
    105     bg="#ffffff",
    106     font=("Arial", 12)
    107 )
    108 result_label.place(x=558, y=100)

File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2819, in Canvas.create_image(self, *args, **kw)
   2817 def create_image(self, *args, **kw):
   2818     """Create image item with coordinates x1,y1."""
-> 2819     return self._create('image', args, kw)

File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py:2805, in Canvas._create(self, itemType, args, kw)
   2803 else:
   2804     cnf = {}
-> 2805 return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
   2806     self._w, 'create', itemType,
   2807     *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist
```

I tried a few things like replacing with another image , using absolute path. It did not fix anything.

Comment: Does your program create more than one instance of `Tk()`?  Images (and various other Tkinter objects) are tied to a particular instance, and simply will not work with widgets that belong to a different instance.  Use `Toplevel()` instead if you need additional windows.

Comment: Also I am not really sure if running tkinter off a pynb is a good solution

Comment: no it is just one instance. I can send the whole code if needed.

Comment: we don't need the whole code, but we do need a [mcve] with as few lines as possible that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @jazlpeak The problem is probably ipynb then, try running it off a py file locally